# Problemas con la creación de token del mercado de pago

Tags: mercadopago, cordova

Tengo problemas en la creación de token del plugin de Cordova de MercadoPago en los últimos días.

El mismo código funcionaba normalmente.

`MercadoPago.createToken(json.public_key, "4235647728025682", 11, 2019, "123", "APROJuan", "CPF", "02014552365", successTokenCreation, failureTokenCreation);`

Objective C

```
- (void)createToken:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command

[MercadoPagoContext setPublicKey:[[command arguments] objectAtIndex:0]];
NSString* callbackId = [command callbackId];
NSInteger expy = [[[command arguments] objectAtIndex:3] integerValue];
NSInteger expm = [[[command arguments] objectAtIndex:2] integerValue];

CardToken *cardToken =[[CardToken alloc]initWithCardNumber:[[command arguments] objectAtIndex:1] expirationMonth:expm expirationYear:expy securityCode:[[command arguments] objectAtIndex:4] cardholderName:[[command arguments] objectAtIndex:5] docType:[[command arguments] objectAtIndex:6] docNumber:[[command arguments] objectAtIndex:7]];

[MPServicesBuilder createNewCardToken:cardToken success:^(Token * token) {
    CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult
                               resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK
                               messageAsString: [token toJSONString]];

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:callbackId];

} failure:^(NSError * error) {

    NSLog(@"error: %@ \n",[error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

Error: error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (mercadopago.sdk.createNewCardToken error -2.)